# Make cell not clickable, but a button on it should still be clickable

Tags: ios, button, uitableview, clickable

I've a tableView with some cells. Each cell also contains a button. When the user clicks the button, the cell should be unclickable, but not the button. So when the user clicks on the button of a cell which is not clickable, this cell should be clickable again.

I tried:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

...but then the button wasn't clickable anymore.

Thanks to your effort in advance.

**EDIT**
I mean: When I click on a cell a new view opens. But I want, that no action happens, when the cell is not "clickable".

Comment: Try setting `userInteractionEnabled` on the individual controls.

Comment: @MarcusAdams But how can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unclickable in which way? If you just want the cell to not be selectable, you are probably seeking for this:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

If you want to prevent your code to be executed when the selection is disabled, just check for the selection property inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`method. Something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) {
        //(your code opening a new view)
    }
}
```

Remember, you still have to play with this property, setting to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` when you don't want the cell to be selectable, and setting back to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` (or `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`) when you want it to be selectable again.

Comment: But I can still click on the cell and the new viewController opens...the only difference I recognize is that their is no color when the cell is selected...or am I getting something wrong here

Comment: Edited. Try and see if it helped.

Comment: @LucasEduardo Ok...I understand. Is it also possible to combine this with `prepareForSegue` method as I use storyboard?

Comment: It depends in what you are trying to do. The problem is because in `prepareForSegue` you don't have a reference to the indexPath selected (and consequently the cell), so you would have to store the selected cell in some instance variable or something like that. If the anwser helped you, don't forget to accept it in order to remove your question from the Unanswered section!

Comment: for swift 2 the syntax slightly differs:
`cell.selectionStyle = .None;`

Comment: This is worked in Swift5. I have 4 buttons in my static tableView cell.

Answer (score 3):

Swift version:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove selection by setting `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` as the `selectionStyle`.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

And do nothing in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

You can be selective in that delegate method for example if only the first row in the first section has the button and should do nothing :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathForDisabledCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0
                                                               inSection:0];
    if([indexPath compare:indexPathForDisabledCell] != NSOrderedSame) {
        //Do whatever you do with other cells
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done through Interface Builder using **User Defined Runtime Attributes** on the TableViewCell:

`Key Path | Type | Value`

`selectionStyle | Number | 0`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle